# Why do products look like co products but with arrows flipped in Category Theory?

Tags: category-theory

Here is the diagram for product of two object in a category:

[image]

And here is the one for coproduct:

[image]

One looks like the other but with the arrows flipped. Is there any deeper meaning to this fact?

Comment: It means that the product (resp. coproduct) of two objects of a category $C$ is its coproduct (resp. product) in $C^{\rm op}$, the [opposite category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opposite_category) of $C$.

Comment: What would this mean in the context of Set Theory? I think I get what you mean but I am having hard time understanding what this would mean in a given context @azif00

Comment: I don't quite know how to answer your question, but another way of saying what I said earlier is that the coproduct is nothing but the [dual](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_(category_theory)) concept of the product.

Comment: If you have a thing defined by some diagram, the object defined by the opposite diagram is generally called a cothing.

Comment: Your observation is the reason this object is called "coproduct".

Answer (score 1):

The deeper meaning to this as mentioned in the comments is that products and coproducts are *dual* to one another in the sense that given a category $\mathcal{C}$, the product of two objects in $\mathcal{C}^{\mathrm{op}}$ is their coproduct in $\mathcal{C}$. If we take $\mathcal{C}=\mathrm{Set}$, then the dual object to the product of two sets is their *disjoint union*.

If we realize the product of two objects in $\mathcal{C}$ as the limit of a diagram: $$D:\{\mathbf{0}, \mathbf{1}\}\longrightarrow\mathcal{C}$$
where $\{\mathbf{0},\mathbf{1}\}$ is the category with two objects and only identity morphisms, then the (co)product is the *(co)limit* of this diagram. Thus this is a single case of dual constructions throughout mathematics which we can refer to generally as the duality between limits and colimits. Maybe the next simplest example to consider is the duality between equalizers and coequalizers.

(Co)equalizers are the (co)limits of diagrams: $$D:\{\mathbf{0}\rightrightarrows\mathbf{1}\}\longrightarrow\mathcal{C}$$

If we restrict our attention to $\mathcal{C}=\mathrm{Set}$ then such a diagram picks out a pair of sets and a pair of parallel functions: $$A\rightrightarrows B$$ let's call them $f$ and $g$. The limit of such a diagram is some set $E$ with canonical map $E\xrightarrow{e} A$ satisfying $f\circ e = g\circ e$ such that for any other object $D$ with map $D\xrightarrow{h} A$, there exists a unique map $D\xrightarrow{\iota}E$ such that $\iota = e\circ h$. You can draw a similar diagram to the one for the product here where $\iota$ is the dotted arrow.

We can identify the set $E$ as the following one: $$E = \{a\in A\mid f(a) = g(a)\}$$ and the canonical map $e:E\to A$ is just the inclusion.

Now, if you dualize everything (flip all the arrows), you can ascertain the definition of the colimit of the diagram which is the *coequalizer* of $f$ and $g$. The set satisfying the universality condition will be the quotient $B/\sim$  where $\sim$ is the equivalence relation generated by $f(a)\sim g(a)$. The canonical map is of course the canonical quotient map $B\xrightarrow{q} B/\sim$.